# PHP communicating by SOAP or CURL

Tags: php, curl, wsdl, openssl, soap-client

I need to connect to a server environment and the options told are:

**wsdl:** http://info.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt/NR/rdonlyres/A75E1110-7EB8-479E-BC09-6D5B726F6A1C/0/documentosTransporte.wsdl

**url:** https://servicos.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt:701/sgdtws/documentosTransporte

With that in mind, I need to send an XML to that host and receive from it a response. I've tried already with SoapClient() without any success and now I'm trying with CURL.

```
$xml  = 'my xml...';
$soap = curl_init();

$soapAction = 'https://servicos.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt/sgdtws/documentosTransporte/';
$action  = 'https://servicos.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt:701/sgdtws/documentosTransporte';

curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type:text/xml;Charset=UTF-8',
                'Accept: text/xml',
                'Cache-Control: no-cache',
                'SoapAction=' . $soapAction
            ));

curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_URL, $action);
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, 'TesteWebServices.pfx'); 
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, 'TESTEwebservice');

$response = curl_exec($soap); 

if(curl_errno($soap)){
   echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($soap);
   return;
}
```

And currently I'm receiving the following error:

> Curl error: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in
>   certificate chain

If I change some of the variables of CURL like so:

```
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, 'pfxCert.pem');
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, 'PEM');
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, 'TESTEwebservice');
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, 'pfxKey.pem'); 
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, 'PEM');
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, 'okgo');
```

Then I receive a different error.

> Curl error: unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong
>   pass phrase?)

Although I'm 100% sure that both passwords are correct.

Finally, the files `pfxCert.pem` and `pfxKey.pem` were originated from `TesteWebServices.pfx` this way:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in TesteWebServices.pfx -nocerts -out pfxKey.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in TesteWebServices.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out pfxCert.pem
```

Comment: Is it possible that the server doesn't accept self-signed certificates?